# Why doesn't the state of matter oscillates between solid , liquid and gaseous phase?

Tags: forces, phase-transition, states-of-matter

I was reading about the [London dispersion forces](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_dispersion_force) and it is written that it arises due to an asymmetric distribution of charges in an atom at an instant which gives rise to a temporal dipole and this temporal dipole then induces a dipole in nearer atoms and thus they experience the intermolecular forces.

[This site](https://www.chem.purdue.edu/gchelp/liquids/problems/dispere_ex1.html) says that $Cl_2$ and $Br_2$ can exist as solid because of this force at lower temperature and can exist in liquid form too.

So , my question is that since this force is due to temporal dipole moment then **why doesn't the state of the compound or molecule (held together by dispersion forces) keep on oscillating between solid , liquid and gaseous phase ?**

---

One thing which I think for the above question is that we need a repulsive force to separate two closer molecules and this is the reason why we don't notice oscillations . **Am I right ?**

---

Okay if my intuitions are correct then again there is a question.

If the forces are temporal , then surely the strengths of the compound in solid phase must be changing i.e. **if it is harder at an instant then after sometime it must be softer and can be easily converted into gas with a negligible effort or with a single blow of hand or even with a beam of photons**.

But I don't think we notice such strange things in our daily life.

**So why don't we notice such transformations ?**

Answer (score 4):

The dipole interactions may oscillate (at very high frequencies) but they average out over time (and billions of atoms) into a steady force.  The ability of this force to hold atoms together against thermal agitation generally depends on the temperature. A change of state is associated with a significant amount of energy (the heat of fusion or vaporization) and time.  You wont see it occurring in a random manner.

Comment: Of course, any fluctuation that happens to occur at the surface that allows a molecule to detach and depart into the void is irreversible and doesn't average out. This is the origin of evaporation/sublimation into the gas state. We don't see the corresponding solid→liquid fluctuations at the surface because the positive surface tension of liquids requires a large number of molecules to undergo the phase transition essentially simultaneously to nucleate a droplet.

Comment: @R.W. Bird you didn't answer my second question I guess .

Comment: @R.W. Bird can you edit your answer for the second part of my question ?